# Why operator address-of has not effect?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Why does the following function call behave the same with and without the "address-of" operator?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int, int);
void fun(int, int, void (*)(int, int));

int main()
{
    fun(3,4, &sum); // Why does this line work with and without the `&`?
    return 0;
}

void sum(int a, int b)
{
    cout << a+b;
}

void fun(int a, int b, void (*ptr)(int, int))
{
    (*ptr)(a,b);
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure about your question, but any decent C book should mention that functions *decay* to pointers to themselves. To `sum` will decay to `&sum`. Similarly to how arrays decays to pointers to their first element.

Comment: Dude, I found an excellent explanation on C++ Premier, Fifth edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C 2018 6.3.2.1 3 says:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning *type*" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning *type*".

C++ performs the same automatic conversion, although the specification of this is spread across several clauses in the standard.

Thus, in `fun(3,4, &sum);`, `sum` is not converted to a pointer because it is the operand of `&`. But then the `&` takes the address, producing a pointer to the function. Alternatively, in `fun(3,4, sum);`, `sum` is automatically converted to a pointer to the function, producing the same result.

In `(*ptr)(a,b)`, the `*` and parentheses are unnecessary. The function call operator, `(…)`, technically takes a pointer to a function as its left operand, so `ptr(a, b)` supplies that pointer. In `(*ptr)(a,b)`, `*ptr` dereferences the pointer, producing a function designator. Then this function designator is automatically converted back to a pointer. Thus, the expression is equivalent to `(&*ptr)(a, b)`, which is equivalent to `ptr(a, b)`.

In fact, if you write `(**ptr)(a, b)`, `*ptr` becomes `&*ptr` as above, and then `*&*ptr` produces the function designator again, and that is automatically converted again, yielding `&*&*ptr`, which is equivalent to `ptr`. You can add any number of `*` operators, and they will all be undone by the automatic conversions; you can write `(**************ptr)(a, b)`.

There is also an automatic adjustment of function parameter declarations corresponding to the automatic conversion. If a parameter is declared to be a function, as in the `ptr` of `void fun(int a, int b, void ptr(int, int))`, it is automatically adjusted to be a pointer to a function, as if it had been written `void fun(int a, int b, void (*ptr)(int, int))`.